# How to make System.Net.WebProxy to not bypass local urls?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, restsharp, webproxy

I am trying to make [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) work with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) witch uses `System.Http.WebProxy`, so I want it to be set to `localhost:8888` or `127.0.0.1:8888`

Here is the code:

```
    var webProxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8888"))
    {
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false
    };

    var bypassed = webProxy.IsBypassed(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1"));
    Console.WriteLine(bypassed);
```

Outputs: **true**

MSDN states the following:

> The **IsBypassed** method is used to determine whether to bypass the proxy
> server when accessing an Internet resource.
>
> The BypassProxyOnLocal and BypassList properties control the return
> value of the **IsBypassed** method.
>
> **IsBypassed** returns **true** under any of the following conditions:
>
> - If BypassProxyOnLocal is **true** and *host* is a local URI. Local requests
>   are identified by the lack of a period (.) in the URI, as in
>   "http://webserver/".
> - If host matches a regular expression in BypassList.
> - If Address is null.
>
> All other conditions return **false**.

I don't understand why in my case it returns **true**, is this a bug? How to make it work then? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **hard-coded behavior** in the implementation of the HTTP client library in the .Net framework, mirroring the behavior of WinInet prior to Internet Explorer 9.

See [Monitor traffic to localhost from IE or .NET](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/MonitorLocalTraffic) from the Fiddler web site explains how to deal with it.

Comment: As a slight modification to what Fiddler suggests: if you use `oSession.hostname = "localhost"` then it will maintain your port number instead of changing it to 8081.

Comment: (Note the usage of `oSession.hostname` instead of `oSession.host`)